# Let $f :A\rightarrow B$ be a function and let $X$ and $Y$ be any subsets of $B$, then

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

> a) $f^{-1}(X\setminus Y)=f^{-1}(X)\setminus f^{-1}(Y).$
>
> b) $Z\subset f^{-1}(f(Z))$ for all $Z\subset A$.
>
> c) For all $X\subset B,\, f(f^{-1}(X))\subset X.$

I have already studied Sets and Relations, but I'm struggling with functions. Please someone explain and show how to solve these problems.

Answer (score 1):

You should really show some effort. I will demonstrate one, and leave the rest for you:

$z \in f^{-1}(X - Y) \iff f(z) \in X - Y \iff f(z) \in X \land f(z) \notin Y \iff z \in f^{-1}(X) \land z \notin f^{-1}(Y) \iff z \in f^{-1}(X) - f^{-1}(Y) $

such that $f^{-1}(X - Y) = f^{-1}(X) - f^{-1}(Y)$

You should be able to do the rest now. Or at least, you should show your attempts.